# Duplicated() function as boolean indexing generates different result compares with drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, transform

The data frame looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'k1':['one']*3 + ['two']*4,'k2':[1,1,2,3,3,4,4]})
```

When I am checking duplicates, I get boolean index by doing
`df.duplicated()`, then I use it as the filter
`df[df.duplicated()]` which shows different result compares with `df.drop_duplicates()`

An additional row has been created in the result

```
2 one 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drop_duplicate` will drop all duplicated row . `duplicated` will return False for the first item and True for the other row of duplicates when it has the duplicate , so they are different function target for different problem .

```
df.duplicated()
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
dtype: bool

df.drop_duplicates()
    k1  k2
0  one   1
2  one   2
3  two   3
5  two   4
```

---

How to make the output same ?

Check the unique value

```
df[~df.duplicated(keep=False)]
    k1  k2
2  one   2

df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    k1  k2
2  one   2
```